# Converting a String to Date in Swift

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Is it posible to convert a string to time with a specific format?

I want to convert a string to time with format "HH:MM:SS". I tried to search for some help, but nothing.

Comment: There are countless examples and documentation showing the proper format specifiers. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: BTW - If you are planning to show the times to a user, it's best to avoid fixed formats. Use `timeStyle` so the result is appropriate to the user's locale and preferences.

Comment: hi every one it is because i want to compare dates. thanks for the documentation i´ll check it.